# The Android Gradle plugin supports only Crashlytics Gradle plugin version 1.25.4 and higher. Project '***' is using version 1.25.1

Tags: android

Evironment: Android Studio 3.2

I got a error

> The Android Gradle plugin supports only Crashlytics Gradle plugin
>   version 1.25.4 and higher. Project '***' is using version 1.25.1.

Any idea how to solve? Thank you.

Comment: check the Project `build.gradle` file, under `buildscript { depedencies { ` check for `classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.25.1'` and change that to .4

Comment: Reply to zapl: Thank you. By the way, do you know where can I find the latest version of 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.25.4'

Comment: Here you can find the complete list: https://s3.amazonaws.com/fabric-artifacts/public/io/fabric/tools/gradle/maven-metadata.xml

Comment: there was a problem with version 1.26, with version 1.25.4 all ok

Answer (score 58, accepted):

The "Crashlytics Gradle plugin" is found in gradle in the `io.fabric.tools:gradle` package as mentioned on https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started#android

You should find that in your projects root `build.gradle` file. Similar to this

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.25.1'
        ...
    }
}

allprojects {
    ...
```

Once you change it to `classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.25.4'` that error should go away.

The versions of a maven dependency can also be found in its maven repository under

> https://maven.fabric.io/public/io/fabric/tools/gradle/maven-metadata.xml

That trick should work for all maven repositories once you know the url:

> `<repo-base-url>/${groupId.replace('.','/')}/${artifactId}/maven-metadata.xml`

You can also use a gradle plugin such as https://github.com/ben-manes/gradle-versions-plugin to have it lookup the latest versions in those `maven-metadata.xml` files for you.

If you simply want the latest you can also define the version with a wildcard, e.g.

```
classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+' // or even ...:gradle:+'
```

That would always give you the latest version that starts with `1.`. It's rarely done in production since builds become less deterministic when dependency versions change from one moment to the next. But it's good to check whether gradle downloads a newer version.

Furthermore, Android Studio does check versions too, however you don't see the difference between there being no new version and when the check wasn't done yet. But when it did, you'll get an inspection hint and it can be quick fixed.

Comment: Thats not solving the issue still.. No matter to what version i update I am getting this error every time and the version displayed in the error is wrong for me

Comment: @AlwaysConfused hi, have you managed to solve the issue? I have a similar problem and no matter which version I am specifying this issue persists. Also my `react-native-firebase` is upgraded to maximum version...

Comment: Closing the loop here. My gradle was executed on CI against outdated cache. It all solved by invaliding the cache so there's no issue with gradle or `react-native-firebase` itself.

Comment: In my case I changed "classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.25.4'" to "classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.28.0'" and it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

This *exact* error message can be encountered another way: outdated version of `react-native-firebase`. Zapl's solution is more likely necessary, but you *may* simply need to update your package.json.

In my case, a `git merge` had brought in all the latest latest firebase SDK for Android in my /android directory, but my `package.json` was left referring to an older version of react-native-firebase (3.x). I set it to 5.3 and problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

For those of you running into this issue while trying to use the [firebase_crashlytics](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_crashlytics) plugin for Flutter, be sure you **only** follow the instructions for the plugin itself on the pub.dev page there. Do not follow the instructions on the [Firebase site](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started). Doing both will create conflicts.

You may still have to update the version number for the `io.fabric.tools:gradle` classpath in your `android/build.gradle` file to the version the error log is asking for.

**Edit**: For those looking for the latest fabric version, you can find it here: https://s3.amazonaws.com/fabric-artifacts/public/io/fabric/tools/gradle/maven-metadata.xml

Comment: This is what i needed! Thanks!