# The Android Gradle plugin supports only Crashlytics Gradle plugin version 1.28.0 and higher

Tags: android, firebase

> The Android Gradle plugin supports only Crashlytics Gradle plugin version 1.28.0 and higher.
>   The following dependencies do not satisfy the required version:
>   root project 'E-commerceCustomerFYP-master' -> io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.25.4

Answer (score 10):

Your `android\build.gradle` file should show you where the problem lies. This issue is probably under the `dependencies`:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.28.0'
}
```

Changing your version (1.25.4) to 1.28.0 may fix the issue (or another later version [see below]).

Also, if you are using Flutter and trying to use the [firebase_crashlytics](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_crashlytics) plugin, be sure you are **only** following those instructions and **NOT** following the instructions on the Firebase site [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started). If you do both, you will run into conflicts that seem to start with the issue you posted here.

You may find more info here: [The Android Gradle plugin supports only Crashlytics Gradle plugin version 1.25.4 and higher. Project '***' is using version 1.25.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52506288/the-android-gradle-plugin-supports-only-crashlytics-gradle-plugin-version-1-25-4)

**Edit**: If you want to find the latest `io.fabric.tools:grade` version, they are listed here: https://s3.amazonaws.com/fabric-artifacts/public/io/fabric/tools/gradle/maven-metadata.xml

Comment: As of Nov 15th, crashlythics moved away from Fabric. The upgrade guide seems to be ignoring React Native so it's unclear.

Answer (score 0):

update your version or comment below line

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.31.2'
}
```